# How to dump Edge Driver (Chromium) verbose log output into txt file using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge

Learning from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=java) , I managed to launch an Edge Chromium browser.

```js
else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\msedgedriver.exe");

  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.verboseLogging", "true");
  EdgeDriverService service = EdgeDriverService.createDefaultService();
  EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
  driver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);
  log.debug("Launching Edge");
}
```

When I run the codes, I can see Edge print out some verbose log in the console.

```css
[1617234463.144][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: DOM.childNodeCountUpdated 18CEE59C54283295B454E2340ACD283A {
   "childNodeCount": 21,
   "nodeId": 12
}
[1617234463.144][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: DOM.childNodeCountUpdated 18CEE59C54283295B454E2340ACD283A {
   "childNodeCount": 20,
   "nodeId": 12
}
```

How can we write that verbose log into txt file , instead printing out to console only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try to make a test with the sample code below may help you to store verbose log output to a text file.

Sample JAVA code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "Path_to_Edge_driver\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.logfile", "Path_to_log_file\\log.txt");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.verboseLogging", "true");
        
    EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
    //edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate");
       
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
        
    driver.get("https://Your_site_address_here...");
}
```

Further, you can try to modify the code sample as per your requirements.